# Resize byte array size

Tags: android, arrays, bluetooth, byte

I've got a byte[] declared this way:

```
byte[] buffer;
buffer = new byte[128];
```

Then, I get the received data's size via bluetooth with:

```
bytes = GlobalVar.mmInStream.read(buffer);
```

Bytes is the size of the received data. What I need is to resize the buffer to the size of it's containig data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can't resize an array (they are immutable) you need to create a copy:

```
byte[] data = new byte[bytes]
System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, data, 0, bytes)
```

However it's definitely more efficient to continue using `buffer` and just read it until `bytes` for whatever reason you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reallocate memory for your buffer with the right size as the array is of fixed size by default. 
EDIT:
in case buffer already contains data and you do not want to lose them, you can also use:

```
buffer = Arrays.copyOf(buffer, newsize);
```

Which move your current buffer data to a newly allocated memory.